# Simulate com port on pc to be recognised by other pc

Tags: serial-port, com-port

Currently I have a server, that communicates with a projector through a RS232. The server opens a com port when the projector is connected. The same happens to any PC when a certain type of device is connected through the USB (lets say an Arduino for example). What I want to do it basically replace the projector with a PC/Arduino/Raspberry without the server noticing anything. That would mean the server will recognise the connected PC and open a COM port for it. What do I need to do on the PC so that it automatically opens a com port on the server? I guess there is something very basic that any printer, Arduino, projector etc does, that computers recognise it as a "com port device".

P.S. Doesn't matter the OS on the PC, I just need to make it work and then implement w/e I need to do with the established communication over the port.

P.S.2 I've searched a lot about it, but probabl I am doing it wrong, because I didn't find my type of question anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

COM ports are basically hardware that is detected by the system. Let's say, if an Arduino is connected to a PC, it has its onboard USB to TTL converter which can be found in the device manager(if using windows). Similar USB to TTL converters are there in the market like CP2102, PL2303 which acts like a COM port even if no device is connected further to it. it may be possible that the program you are using(as you referred server) may be sending some data over the serial port and verifying the hardware.

What you need to do to replace it is, first of all, find the baud rate at which the communication is going on, then, listen over the serial lines which machine is sending which message in the sequence(there must be a handshake as I mentioned earlier), if a complicated algorithm is not used by the device, you can simply mimic the device by sending same messages over serial.

Comment: Both of you confuse and mix RS232 and USB, they are not the same hardware and are not using same type of drivers so plug and play may not even be relevant. What might works is N Arduino with TTL to RS232 adapter and a bit of software on the Arduino to act as the projector.

Comment: what he is intending to do is serial communication, whether he uses hardware RS232 or USB to serial converters(easy to use and USB available on every machine).